# Preventing a button from being clicked on different devices at the same time

Tags: android-studio, onclicklistener, corruption, simultaneous

In my android app I have some code that runs when the user clicks a button. I want to prevent two different users on different devices from clicking the button at the same time. Is this possible and if so how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn about multi-threading to achieve this.
[See this here](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads) or [here](https://medium.com/better-programming/threading-in-android-129b8688436a)

You basically need to understand about synchronization in multi threading.